# How to clear database table for embeddable type in Quarkus test

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I need to clear the tables of my database in a Quarkus application. I am able to achieve this for Entities extending either `PanacheEntity` or `PanacheEntityBase` by calling `entity.deleteAll()`. How  can I clear table for embeddable types?

Comment: @TestTransactional will revert database changes after every test and may solve your problem

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci still didn't work for me. I think I'll go with the way I  did in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to fix the issue myself and here's what I did:

1. Inject an EntityManager instance
2. In the clean up method (tearDown() in my case), I wrote and executed a native query to clear my table "course_description".
   Note: I have an entity `Course` and an embeddable `CourseDescription`. `CourseDescription` is embedded in `Course`
   Example:

```
@Embedded
@ElementCollection
public List<CourseDescription> courseDescriptions;
```

My Test Class:

```
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;
```

...

```
    @AfterEach
    @Transactional
    public void tearDown(){
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("DELETE FROM course_description")
                .setHint(COMMENT, "Custom cleanup for embeddable type CourseDescription");
        query.executeUpdate();
        Course.deleteAll();
    }
```

**Update:** I could have simply set CourseDescription to null and let JPA take care of the cleanup.

```
    @AfterEach
    @Transactional
    public void tearDown(){
        Course.findAll().stream()
                .forEach(course -> {
                    Course c = (Course) course;
                    c.courseDescription = null;
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use the JUnit 5 extension with Flyway to manage your schema and also reset the state of the database on each test

You can find the extension here: https://github.com/radcortez/flyway-junit5-extensions/

And the Quarkus example here: https://github.com/radcortez/flyway-junit5-extensions/tree/master/examples/quarkus

Comment: I think I'll just go ahead and wire up an EntityManager. this was helpful.